# Axler example 1.24: $F^S$ is a vector space when $S \neq \emptyset$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

In Example 1.24, Axler states that when $S \neq \emptyset$, the set $F^S$ with the usual addition and multiplication for functions is a vector space.

I'm fine with the verification, but I'm interested in why we require $S \neq \emptyset$. If $S$ were empty, the only element of $F^S$ is the empty function. I don't really know how I'd talk about addition and multiplication with respect to the empty function, but I assume the axioms would be vacuously satisfied, with the exception of the additive identity. The $0$ function is certainly missing, but could the empty function act, itself, as the "additive identity"?

I suppose I'm unsure of whether the book excluded $S = \emptyset$ because some axioms would be broken or because it would be a nuisance to define what exactly addition and multiplication mean for the empty function.

Answer (score 2):

The only explanation is undue fear (by the author) of fear (by the audience) of the void. In fact one needs $0$-dimensional spaces$~Z$ on many occasions; the unique basis of such a space is the empty sequence of vectors, and the coordinate map for that empty basis of $Z$ is the isomorphism $Z\to F^0$ to the also $0$-dimensional space of $0$-tuples of scalars. This does not quite involve $F^\emptyset$ (because I would like to distinguish the (unordered) empty set from the (ordered) $0$-tuple), but there are occasions where one considers functions on (unordered) sets and then one does obtain $F^\emptyset$ when the set happens to be empty, and which behaves like any other $0$-dimensional space.

Operations on functions on the empty set are defined just like the are on other function spaces: $f+g:\emptyset\to F$ is the map $x\mapsto f(x)+g(x)$, whose only particularity here is that the expression $f(x)+g(x)$ is never used because there are no values $x$ is the domain of the function. (Of course there is only one choice here for $f$ and $g$, and we could have defined for instance $f+g=f$, but why make an exceptional definition if the usual definition works fine?) Scalar multiplication is defined as usual similarly (and also always results in the unique function $\emptyset\to F$).

All axioms of vector spaces can be shown to hold without difficulty for any space $F^X$ and the choice $X=\emptyset$ needs absolutely no special consideration, except maybe for didactic reasons to stress that that is no reason for an exception. But somehow for anti-didactic reasons many authors prefer to make exceptions for the empty set anyway, maybe in order to not to distract the fragile minds of their readers by the vertigo possibly caused by thinking about operations involving the empty set, even though perfectly well defined. The unfortunate consequence is that fear for the empty set gets reinforced by the fact that one never gets to grips with its (very simple) rules. When asked to find a basis of a (sub)space that happens to have dimension$~0$, it is natural to think the very first time about the singleton consisting of the zero vector, but one should go through the learning experience of finding this to be wrong (for various reasons: the number of vectors does not match the dimension of the sapce, and the set of vectors is not linearly independent).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. By "function over $\Bbb R$ do you mean a function _to_ $\Bbb R$ (and presumably defined on the empty set here, so a function $\emptyset\to\Bbb R$)? Then I don't see why you should write $f$ for the left operand and $\varnothing$ for the second; both are the same. And as my answer indicates, functions $\emptyset\to\Bbb R$ (not really a plural) are added and scalar-multiplied following the usual definitions, though there is only one possible value to pick from for the result, so one could use an alternative formulation that ends up making this forced choice.

Comment: Ant the vector space axioms that are identities are trivially satisfied, since any two expressions that designate an element from a singleton set are necessarily equal. There isn't really any axiom that could conceivably fail here; the existence of a neutral element (zero vector) is the only one that comes to mind; but since the space is not empty one can make a choice, and since all that is required for a neutral element are certain equalities, that unique choice will satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the zero element exists because $\varnothing + \varnothing=\varnothing$, vacuously. (+1) btw, this is a great answer.